# How to Install & Deploy a java app (.jsp file) in apache tomcat

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

I have successfully installed apache tomcat & verified it to be working using the curl command

```
curl http://localhost:8080/
```

Tomcat is installed in

```
   /var/lib/tomcat8/
                   webapps/ROOT/index.html
                   webapps/ROOT/META-INF
                   lib
```

I have received following structure of the java app in a zip file

```
App/
   build.xml
   deploy.sh
   run.sh
   www/
      *.jsp files
      WEB-INF/lib/*.jar files
```

I want to install and run this app on my server. How can I do that. Specifically I want to know where to place these folders. Do I need to run any of the deploy or build files. Do i need to install the jar files? If I directly run one of the .jsp files from curl command, it crashes due to missing java class.

Perhaps I am missing something obvious but I am new to java env and could not find it from google.

Comment: Create `.war` file and put this file into webapps folder of server. That's it.

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how to create .war file. Also where should I put the whole app dir structure

Comment: Which ide are you using?

Comment: I tried it - created a app.war file & placed it in webapps folder. I am still getting the same error:  Unable to compile class for JSP:

Comment: Not using any IDE. working directly on linux-apache

Comment: check the java version of the server and java version used for compiling are matching.

Comment: where to check the java version used for compiling

Comment: You said that no IDE using then how can i say that? Through terminal try `java -version`.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't tried it yet, consider using [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) to build your projects.

This will automate and simplify a lot of similar work for you, like creating a .war file and deploying your project to Tomcat. With Maven, you have to set the `<packaging>war</packaging>` in pom.xml (a project configuration file) and run `mvn tomcat7:deploy` command.

For details look at the above link to Maven docs or for instance check out [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/tomcat-deploy-war).

You can also use the Tomcat Manager under (default) http://localhost:8080/manager to deploy the .war file manually.

Comment: From the comments under your question, the error "Unable to compile class for JSP" might relate to the fault in JSP syntax. Please check if JSP scriptlets/tags are used correctly.

Comment: I had noticed that the App was using apache ant, from the run.sh & deploy.sh files. Based on your answer I installed ant (similar to maven i guess). When I execute run.sh, it is asking for the location of SDK directory.  Do I need to install SDK? I have installed java + apache tomcat. I only want to run a jsp from curl.

Comment: I am actually not familiar with Ant, but to create a .war file you'll 99% need SDK (JDK), since packaging is a part of project build process and Ant is only a tool. And for building Java apps, JRE is not enough. If you don't use any IDE, after creating a .war file with Ant, try running tomcat and using the Tomcat Manager to deploy the app.